# A better way to organize view models in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, organization

In asp.net mvc3, I currently have a single file `ViewModels.cs` which holds all of the viewmodel classes I use. The size of the file is only at 180 lines of code at the moment and is pretty easy to manage with `#region`s.

However, I fear these models could begin to add up. Moreover, it seems to me that if I break each view model class into its own file I will end up with a large amount of viewmodel.cs files.

I attempted to just make a generic view model but was advised against using generic classes as view models.

What is a better way to organize these view models, or a better approach in general to view models?

Comment: What is wrong with "large amount" of viewModel.cs? If large amount of views are fine so should large amount of viewModel.cs too. You may want to organize those in sub-folders based on the functional areas.

Comment: @amit_g - I am not arguing that there is something wrong with a "large amount" of viewModel.cs files aside from the fact that I prefer not to have my solution explorer look like a version of Price of Persia (Which I am currently working on with regards to controllers and views).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My standard approach has been:

- **Project.Web**

  - [Content]
  - [Controllers]

    - FooController.cs
  - [ViewModels]

    - FooViewModel.cs
    - BarViewModel.cs
  - [Scripts]
  - [Views]

    - [Foo]
    - [Shared]

And , if necessary, you can add a reference to the namespace in your config file so you don't end up adding `ViewModels.` to every reference:

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="MyProject.Web.ViewModels" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

If that's of any help. I've also seen people break out the `ViewModels` / `Models` folder in to sub-directories based on controller, but I don't usually go to that extent (though wouldn't hurt).

Comment: Thanks for the input, it is of help. I like the point about including default namespaces.

Comment: @TravisJ: FWIW, Take a look at [nerddinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/). It's a decent sized project that demonstrates a lot of the common practices (structure, routes, theming, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have looked at nerddinner and prodinner and have copies of their code. However, in my opinion abstraction levels depend on project size and I am not sure I need to go as crazy as prodinner does with its abstraction. Nerddinner does a pretty standard organization of the view models.